# Is the tag "measurement" a synonym of "observational-astronomy"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I came across the rather rare (8 occurrences as of February 12, 2021) and yet undefined tag [measurement](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) which seems to be a synonym for the ubiquitous (728 times used) tag [observational-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observational-astronomy).

Do you agree? If so, could somebody please define the synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to be the questions tagged [measurement](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) that are about some kind of measuring. I think that for all except "measure the age of the universe" the [observational-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observational-astronomy) tag would be fine.

I've no objection to the proposed synonymization.

- [How do we measure the age of the universe?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35986/7982)
- [How do we measure the brightness of the stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36025/7982)
- [What instruments are used to measure the distance to the Sun?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39255/7982)
- [When was the diameter of Titan first measured?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39022/7982)
- [Determining wind speed distribution on Mars using dune shapes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40282/7982)
- [How was the axial tilt of planets measured?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41334/7982)

Comment: Merge and synonym complete.

Comment: @called2voyage It took me quite a while to realize that you have the essential diamond behind your username, thanks for your effort!